# Upgrade processor in Dell Inspiron E1705

Tags: laptop, cpu, upgrade, dell-inspiron

I'm looking to upgrade the processor in my older Dell Inspiron E1705.  The laptop is currently running an Intel T2400 @ 1.83GHZ.  First, is this something that is even possible to do?  Second, what processors are still for sale that would be a great upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the motherboard, look for what does it support. Then just go to eBay or a trusted site where you can buy used mobile CPUs and get one which is supported by the motherboard/chipset.

Also, check with Google. Try typing `Inspiron E1705 cpu upgrade` and such. Someone may have done this already and got some info about what works and what does not.